# Webhook trigger in Microsoft Logic App doesn't fire

Tags: webhooks, azure-logic-apps

It's my first time with Microsoft Logic Apps. I'm following the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-webhook) to subscribe to  third-party APIs webhooks for a specific event. The documentation says:

> When you save your logic app with a webhook trigger, or when you change your logic app from disabled to enabled, the webhook trigger subscribes to the specified service or endpoint by registering a callback URL with that service or endpoint. The trigger then uses that URL to run the logic app as necessary. Like the request trigger, the logic app fires immediately when the expected event happens.

If I'm not wrong, this means that a POST request is made to register to the webhook service as soon as I save my logic app. My problem is that the trigger is never fired, although the same works fine with a Node.js server.

The documentation also reports that

> The steps assume that you have already deployed or are accessing an API that follows the webhook subscribe and unsubscribe pattern in logic apps.

Maybe this could be the problem, because the APIs that I'm using don't seem to be compliant to the subscribe/unsubscribe pattern. I'm asking for help: is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Did you add at least one action as stated in the documentation ?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I add the "send email" extension to get notified about the trigger, but  I didn't receive any.

Comment: include screenshots please, the reason you havent gotten an answer is because your question doesnt have enough detail in what you're attempting to do. it's vague and can be interpreted many different ways

Comment: Can you check if the webhook subscribed to the logic app url ?